# Can't get options with $data['variable']

Tags: php, variables

**Can't get options with $data['variable'].**

*(I'm use SMOF - Slightly Modded Options Framework)*

For example in the header.php (index.php, footer.php, etc.):

```
global $data;
$logo_type = stripslashes( $data['type_logo'] );
```

and nothing happens, variable `$logo_type` contains nothing.

But if I use the same code in the \css\styles.php - all works fine.
Code from \css\styles.php:

```
<?php 

/* Background Body */ 
$bg_color = stripslashes ( $data['ct_bg_color'] );

?>

/* Body BG Color */ 
body, .body-class { background-color: <?php echo $bg_color; ?> 
}
```

Function as part of framework :

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Generate a static css file from the defined options
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// This function will generate a static css file which you can use in your theme.
// Some examples of the dynamically generated options has been defined in css/styles.php
function generate_options_css($newdata) {

    $data = $newdata;   
    $css_dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/'; // Shorten code, save 1 call
    ob_start(); // Capture all output (output buffering)

    require($css_dir . 'styles.php'); // Generate CSS

    $css = ob_get_clean(); // Get generated CSS (output buffering)
    file_put_contents($css_dir . 'options.css', $css, LOCK_EX); // Save it

}
```

Link to Framework files: https://github.com/sy4mil/Options-Framework/tree/master/admin/functions

First encountered this problem... And can not understand what could be the problem (php, web hosting, etc.)

Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Please post the relevant code from `css/styles/php`.

Comment: `<?php
     
    /* Background Body */
    $bg_color = stripslashes ( $data['ct_bg_color'] ); 
     
    ?>
    
    /* Body BG Color */
    body, .body-class {
       background-color: <?php echo $bg_color; ?>
    }`

Comment: Please add that as an *edit* to your question, rather than as a comment. :) Also: that doesn't have **all** of the relevant code. To wit: it doesn't include the code that **defines `$data`**.

Comment: It's all code, and it works :) PS: added to the start comment.

Comment: Thanks for the question edit. It helps keep things cleaner, and easier to follow. :) But you've still not added the code from `/css/styles.php` that **defines** `$data`. It's in there, somewhere, in that file.

Comment: Added function to the start comment.

Comment: Okay, we're a step closer. Where that function gets **called**, what is passed as the `$newdata` parameter?

Comment: In general, the problem is not in the framework (because it works fine on the thousands websites), most likely a problem with the PHP settings or Wordpress settings, probably.

Comment: I'm 100% certain it has absolutely nothing to do with PHP settings or WordPress settings. Can you edit your question to include a link to the framework code?

Comment: Hmm... I can't find either a `function generate_options_css($newdata){}` declared, or a `/css/styles.php` file included in the framework.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a **PHP** question, and not a **WordPress** question.

The issue is that global variables don't pass through the `include()`/`require()` call from the template file into `header.php`.

The solution is to *define* `$data` after you *globalize* it.

Without knowing your options framework or your Theme specifically, I can only answer in general terms; that said, you would likely define `$data` like so:

```
global $data;
$data = get_option( 'some_option' );
```

or

```
global $data;
$data = framework_get_options();
```

**Hint: take a look at `/css/styles.php` to see how your framework/Theme does this, specifically.**

Comment: This [framework](https://github.com/sy4mil/Options-Framework/) works fine on the thousands websites. And I'm trying to understand what could be the problem. Unique situation.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this help i use it...

Single Data:

```
<?php global $data; echo $data['your_option_id']; ?>
```

Conditional Data:

```
<?php global $data; ?>
<?php if($data['your_option_id']): ?>
   <?php echo $data['your_option_id']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Conditional Data with Default Data

```
<?php global $data; ?>
<?php if($data['your_option_id']): ?>
   <?php echo $data['your_option_id']; ?>
<?php else: ?>
   My Default Data
<?php endif; ?>
```